# Generate labels, textboxes, validation messages for all properties in view model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view in which I find myself repeating the same code for all properties in my view model, like this:

**View**

```
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
    etc..
```

Is there a way to generate these three elements for *all* properties in my view model without having to write out each? I've tried looping through the model metadata properties but without success:

```
    @foreach(var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
    {

       @Html.LabelFor(property.PropertyName)
       @Html.TextBoxFor(property.PropertyName)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(property.PropertyName)

    }
```

Error:

> The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage.

I've googled for this but couldn't find a good solution.

Comment: it's like trying to use a tool to design a web page for you, isn't it?

Comment: @Leo I don't understand your remark. I'm trying to avoid double code and become a better developer. I'm not asking for a tool, I want to be able to *write* the tool.

Comment: Doesn't scaffolding do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify it by using `UIHint` on your model fields like this:

Model:

```
public class UserModel
{
    [UIHint("UserModelField")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [UIHint("UserModelField")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

EditorTemplate UserModelField.cshtml

```
@model string
@Html.LabelFor(m => m)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m)
```

View ViewUser.cshtml

```
@model UserModel
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Username)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Password)
```

Action

```
public ActionResult ViewUser()
{
    var model = new UserModel { Username = "a", Password = "p" };
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't using "EditorFor" to render labels and such go a bit against the grain of the idea of an EditorTemplate?

Comment: @Moeri I'd say not, it simplifies having to re-enter them each time in a view. You could do it at the object level but that would still mean you would be repeating the label, textbox and validation message for each field and it would be restricted to that model object alone. So you would want them in an editor template anyway IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer is *yes, there is*. You just need to overwrite the `Object` template and there iterate over your model properties, sending them to another template, which generates all your desired elements.

1 - Call the `EditorFor` helper, for the entire `Model` (where you want all your properties to be rendered):

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x, "path_to_custom_Object.cshtml")
```

2 - Iterate your properties (in `Object.cshtml`):

```
foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)        
{
      @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName, "path_to_custom_Template.cshtml")
}
```

3 - Build all your elements (in `Template.cshtml`):

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this works fine:

@foreach(var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
{

   @Html.Label(property.PropertyName)
   @Html.TextBox(property.PropertyName)
   @Html.ValidationMessage(property.PropertyName)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could always write an HTML helper that does this for you:
(All methods fall back to the first method, so if you want to wrap the result into a DIV or so, you only need to change the first implementation)

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns a completely formatted form element for the given expression, including label, input and validation messages
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TProperty"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="html"></param>
    /// <param name="propertyExpression"></param>
    /// <param name="editorHtml"></param>
    /// <param name="labelHtml"></param>
    /// <param name="validationHtml"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString FormElementFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> propertyExpression,
        IHtmlString editorHtml,
        IHtmlString labelHtml,
        IHtmlString validationHtml)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(labelHtml.ToHtmlString() + editorHtml.ToHtmlString() +validationHtml.ToHtmlString());
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Method to build form input with label, editor and validation message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    ///     <code>
    ///         Html.FormElementFor(model => model.MyProperty)
    ///     </code>
    /// </example>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel">Model</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TProperty">Property of the model</typeparam>
    /// <param name="html">This Html Helper</param>
    /// <param name="propertyExpression">Expression to get property of the model</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString FormElementFor <TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> propertyExpression)
    {
        return html.FormElementFor(propertyExpression,
                                   html.EditorFor(propertyExpression),
                                   html.LabelFor(propertyExpression, new  { @class = "control-label" }),
                                   html.ValidationMessageFor(propertyExpression));
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Method to build form input with label, editor and validation message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    ///     <code>
    ///         Html.FormElementFor(model => model.MyProperty, Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyProperty, MySelectList))
    ///     </code>
    /// </example>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel">Model</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TProperty">Property of the model</typeparam>
    /// <param name="html">This Html Helper</param>
    /// <param name="propertyExpression">Expression to get property of the model</param>
    /// <param name="editorHtml">Some custom MvcHtmlString to use as the editor field</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString FormElementFor <TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> propertyExpression,
        IHtmlString editorHtml)
    {
        return html.FormElementFor(propertyExpression,
                                   editorHtml,
                                   html.LabelFor(propertyExpression, new { @class = "control-label" }),
                                   html.ValidationMessageFor(propertyExpression));
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Method to build form input with label, editor and validation message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    ///     <code>
    ///         Html.FormElementFor(model => model.MyProperty, Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.MyBoolean), Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SomeOtherProperty))
    ///     </code>
    /// </example>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TProperty"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="html"></param>
    /// <param name="propertyExpression"></param>
    /// <param name="editorHtml"></param>
    /// <param name="labelHtml"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString FormElementFor <TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> propertyExpression,
        IHtmlString editorHtml,
        IHtmlString labelHtml
        )
    {
        return html.FormElementFor(propertyExpression,
                                   editorHtml,
                                   labelHtml,
                                   html.ValidationMessageFor(propertyExpression));
    }

    /*** EXTRAS ***/

    /// <summary>
    ///     Method to build form input with label, editor and validation message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    ///     <code>
    ///         Html.FormElementFor(model => model.MyProperty, Html.TextAreaFor)
    ///     </code>
    /// </example>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel">Model</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TProperty">Property of the model</typeparam>
    /// <param name="html">This Html Helper</param>
    /// <param name="expression">Expression to get property of the model</param>
    /// <param name="editor">Editor expression that takes the previous expression parameter and converts it into a MvcHtmlString</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString FormElementFor <TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        Func<Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>, MvcHtmlString> editor)
    {
        return FormElementFor(html, expression, editor(expression));
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Method to build form input with label, editor and validation message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    ///     <code>
    ///         Html.FormElementFor(model => model.MyProperty, Html.TextAreaFor, Html.MyDisplayHelper(model => model.MyProperty))
    ///     </code>
    /// </example>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel">Model</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TProperty">Property of the model</typeparam>
    /// <param name="html">This Html Helper</param>
    /// <param name="expression">Expression to get property of the model</param>
    /// <param name="editor">Editor expression that takes the previous expression parameter and converts it into a MvcHtmlString</param>
    /// <param name="labelHtml">Html to use as the label</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString FormElementFor <TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        Func<Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>, MvcHtmlString> editor,
        IHtmlString labelHtml)
    {
        return FormElementFor(html, expression, editor(expression), labelHtml);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Method to build form input with label, editor and validation message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>
    ///     <code>
    ///         Html.FormElementFor(model => model.MyProperty, Html.TextAreaFor, Html.DisplayFor)
    ///     </code>
    /// </example>
    /// <typeparam name="TModel">Model</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TProperty">Property of the model</typeparam>
    /// <param name="html">This Html Helper</param>
    /// <param name="expression">Expression to get property of the model</param>
    /// <param name="editor">Editor expression that takes the previous expression parameter and converts it into a IHtmlString</param>
    /// <param name="label">Label expression that takes the previous expression parameter and converts it into a IHtmlString</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static MvcHtmlString FormElementFor <TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        Func<Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>, MvcHtmlString> editor,
        Func<Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>, MvcHtmlString> label)
    {
        return FormElementFor(html, expression, editor(expression), label(expression));
    }
```

Usage:

```
@Html.FormElementFor(m => m.UserName)
@Html.FormElementFor(m => m.Password, Html.PasswordFor)
```